# How to implement chrome cast device with android things

Tags: chromecast, android-things

Can we develop a chrome cast device by installing android things image on a raspberry pi?

in my project I need to develop a chrome cast device, I searched on an internet that with Android things we can develop any kind of product.

do I get any reference to implement to do this?

thank you for taking the time to read problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol to act as a cast receiver is not available for third-party developers to implement, so you're unable to do that.

If you want to do something that is similar to a Chromecast in functionality, you could take a look at the [Nearby APIs](https://developers.google.com/nearby/), although you will need to build your own client and your own receiver.